# How to change the order of files being read/stored

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a program that reads all text files from a directory and puts it in a excel file. All the text files are name GetData_#+timestamp, for example:

GetData_0.2017-12-04_160809

GetData_1.2017-12-04_160824

GetData_2.2017-12-04_160843

The code I have is:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import config

# Path of directory containing the text files
directory = config.Local_Recieved

# Initialize empty dataframe collector
dframe_collector = []

# For each file in the directory ...
for file_name in sorted(os.listdir(directory)):
    if file_name.startswith('GetData'):
        # Construct full path of file
        file_path = os.path.join(directory, file_name)

        # Read out file and store into a pandas dataframe
        file_dframe = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=';', header=None)
        dframe_collector.append(file_dframe)

# Concatenate individual dataframes into one single dataframe
master_dframe = pd.concat(dframe_collector)

# With newly created excel file ...
with pd.ExcelWriter('DataLog.xlsx') as writer:
    # For each unique parameter that occurs in the first column of the dataframe ...
    for num, (name, group) in enumerate(master_dframe.groupby(0)):
        # Write corresponding data rows to individual excel sheet
        sheet_name = f"Sheet_{num}"
        group.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, header=None, index=None)
```

It works great however I have a problem for this part:

```
 # For each file in the directory ...
    for file_name in sorted(os.listdir(directory)):
        if file_name.startswith('GetData'):
            # Construct full path of file
            file_path = os.path.join(directory, file_name)

            # Read out file and store into a pandas dataframe
            file_dframe = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=';', header=None)
            dframe_collector.append(file_dframe)
```

The order it reads files, is the following GetData_0,1,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,...
The order that I want is GetData_0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,...,501,502

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

You have to rename the files to incorporate leading zeros.  Instead of

GetData_0.2017-12-04_160809

GetData_1.2017-12-04_160824

...

GetData_10.2017-12-04_160843

...

GetData_500.2017-12-04_160843

You should have

GetData_000.2017-12-04_160809

GetData_001.2017-12-04_160824

...

GetData_010.2017-12-04_160843

...

GetData_500.2017-12-04_160843

something along the lines of

```
import os
path = '/path/to/files/'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    prefix = filename.split('_')[0]
    num = filename.split('_')[1].split('.')[0]
    postfix = filename.split('.')[1]
    num = num.zfill(4)
    new_filename = prefix + "_" + num + '.' + postfix
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(path, new_filename))
```